# Test Servlet using JUnit and EasyMock Java

Tags: java, testing, servlets, junit, easymock

I have a servlet and I would like to test it using EasyMock.

My servlet is something like this:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    Population population = new Population();
    Elections elections = new Elections();
    ArrayList<Elector> electorsArl = new ArrayList<Elector>();
    ArrayList<Candidate> candidatesArl =  new ArrayList<Candidate>();

    String[] name = new String[4];
    String[] party = new String[4];
    String[] municipality = {"X", "Y", "Z", "A"};

    name[0] = request.getParameter("cand1");
    party[0] = request.getParameter("party1");
    name[1] = request.getParameter("cand2");
    party[1]= request.getParameter("party2");
    name[2] = request.getParameter("cand3");
    party[2]= request.getParameter("party3");
    name[3] = request.getParameter("cand4");
    party[3]= request.getParameter("party4");

    population.reducePopulation(candidatesArl);

    String[] politicalParty = {candidatesArl.get(0).getPoliticalParty(), candidatesArl.get(1).getPoliticalParty(), candidatesArl.get(2).getPoliticalParty(), candidatesArl.get(3).getPoliticalParty()};

    population.genPopulation(population.getMtyPopulation(), "X", electorsArl);
    population.genPopulation(population.getGpePopulation(), "Y", electorsArl);
    population.genPopulation(population.getSpPopulation(), "Z", electorsArl);
    population.genPopulation(population.getSnPopulation(), "A", electorsArl);

    elections.vote(electorsArl, candidatesArl, politicalParty);
    request.setAttribute("candidate", candidatesArl);

    int totalPopulation = electorsArl.size() + 4;
    int populationVoted = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < candidatesArl.size(); i++){
        populationVoted = populationVoted + candidatesArl.get(i).getAllVotes();
    }
    Integer totalPercentage = (Integer) (populationVoted * 100) / totalPopulation;

    Integer mtyPercentage = (Integer) ((candidatesArl.get(0).getMtyVotes() + candidatesArl.get(1).getMtyVotes() + candidatesArl.get(2).getMtyVotes() + candidatesArl.get(3).getMtyVotes()) * 100) / 90;
    request.setAttribute("mtyPercentage", mtyPercentage);
    Integer spPercentage = (Integer) ((candidatesArl.get(0).getSpVotes() + candidatesArl.get(1).getSpVotes() + candidatesArl.get(2).getSpVotes() + candidatesArl.get(3).getSpVotes()) * 100) / 90;
    request.setAttribute("spPercentage", spPercentage);
    Integer snPercentage = (Integer) ((candidatesArl.get(0).getSnVotes() + candidatesArl.get(1).getSnVotes() + candidatesArl.get(2).getSnVotes() + candidatesArl.get(3).getSnVotes()) * 100) / 90;
    request.setAttribute("snPercentage", snPercentage);
    Integer gpePercentage = (Integer) ((candidatesArl.get(0).getGpeVotes() + candidatesArl.get(1).getGpeVotes() + candidatesArl.get(2).getGpeVotes() + candidatesArl.get(3).getGpeVotes()) * 100) / 90;
    request.setAttribute("gpePercentage", gpePercentage);
    request.setAttribute("totalPercentage", totalPercentage);

    request.setAttribute("winner", elections.getWinnerCandidate(candidatesArl.get(0), candidatesArl.get(1), candidatesArl.get(2), candidatesArl.get(3)));
    try {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
        ElectionsDao electionsDao = (ElectionsDao) context.getBean("electionsDao");
        electionsDao.insertResults(candidatesArl, mtyPercentage, spPercentage, snPercentage, gpePercentage, totalPercentage);
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(FORWARD_PAGE);
        view.forward(request, response); 
    } catch (RuntimeException re){
        logger.error("Runtime exception ocurred in ElectionsServlet.doPost", re);
        response.sendRedirect("error.html");
    }
}
```

What I think about this is that I just have to test everything that has to deal with the request and response because all the other methods are tested in other classes. I was wondering if anyone could help me.

I have this so far:

```
public class ElectionsServletTest extends TestCase {

private IMocksControl mocks;
private ElectionsServlet servlet;

@BeforeClass
public void setUpBeforeClass() {
    mocks = (IMocksControl) createStrictControl();
    servlet = new ElectionsServlet();
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    mocks.reset();
}

@Test
public void testDoPostHttpServletRequestHttpServletResponse() throws IOException, ServletException{
    HttpServletRequest request = mocks.createMock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    HttpServletResponse response = mocks.createMock(HttpServletResponse.class);

    ArrayList<Candidate> candidatesArl =  new ArrayList<Candidate>();

    expect(request.getParameter("cand1")).andReturn("abc");
    expect(request.getParameter("party1")).andReturn("abc");
    expect(request.getParameter("cand2")).andReturn("bcd");
    expect(request.getParameter("party2")).andReturn("bcd");
    expect(request.getParameter("cand3")).andReturn("cde");
    expect(request.getParameter("party3")).andReturn("cde");
    expect(request.getParameter("cand4")).andReturn("def");
    expect(request.getParameter("party4")).andReturn("def");

    candidatesArl.add(new Candidate("abc", 35, "Monterrey", "abc"));
    candidatesArl.add(new Candidate("bcd", 35, "Monterrey", "bcd"));
    candidatesArl.add(new Candidate("cde", 35, "Monterrey", "cde"));
    candidatesArl.add(new Candidate("def", 35, "Monterrey", "def"));

    request.setAttribute("candidate", eq(isA(ArrayList.class)));

    request.setAttribute("mtyPercentage", eq(isA(Integer.class)));
    request.setAttribute("spPercentage", eq(isA(Integer.class)));
    request.setAttribute("snPercentage", eq(isA(Integer.class)));
    request.setAttribute("gpePercentage", eq(isA(Integer.class)));
    request.setAttribute("totalPercentage", eq(isA(Integer.class)));

    request.setAttribute("winner", "abc");

    ElectionsDao electionsDao = mocks.createMock(ElectionsDao.class);
    electionsDao.insertResults(candidatesArl, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45);

    expect(request.getRequestDispatcher("result.jsp")).andReturn(createMock(RequestDispatcher.class));
    mocks.replay();
    servlet.doPost(request, response);
    mocks.verify(); 
}
```

}

Comment: You're right. What kind of help to you need?

Comment: I need to do a test of this... I've been trying to do it using EasyMock but I really don't know how to use it.

Comment: I've edited my post for you to see how I was trying to do it

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you are doing an awful lot of things in that method.
Thus it's going to be hard to test it.
You should extract some logic in separate methods and/or classes.